# How to catch an Enter press in the same time working with blur() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

It's like a to-do list column where you want a link and when clicked on it is converted in to a textbox. I want to catch it when the user is done, when the user press Enter or click somewhere (blur jQuery) to finish.

Demo on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/)

**html**

```
<li style="list-style:none" id="add">Add</a></li>
<input type="text" style="input:focus; outline:none" name="task-group" display:none>
```

**jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=task-group]").hide();

    var addBtn = $("#add");
    var inputBar = $("input[name=task-group]");

    $("#add").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(inputBar).show().focus();
    });
        /*  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && $(inputBar).val() !== ""){
                $(inputBar).hide();
                var new_task_group  = $(inputBar).val();
                $(addBtn).text(new_task_group);
                $(addBtn).show();    
                }
                    else if(e.which !== 13){
                        $(addBtn).show();
                        $(inputBar).hide();
                    }
    });*/

$("input[name=task-group]").blur(function(){
        if($(inputBar).val() !== ""){
        $(this).hide();
        var new_task_group  = $(this).val();
        $(addBtn).text(new_task_group);
        $(addBtn).show();
        } // if close 
        else {
            $(addBtn).show();
            $(inputBar).hide();
        }
    }); 


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Usually,

You can use `.on()` to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function() {
    ...
});
```

Or just pass the function as the parameter to normal event functions:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   ...
}

$('#element')
    .keyup(myFunction)
    .keypress(myFunction)
    .blur(myFunction)
    .change(myFunction)
```

## But,

I don't know how to check while binding, if the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will need to do that in the function, but then we don't know if the function was instantiated due to keypress or blur, so what I did was, on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `blur()` your box, so that function is automatically triggered on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> too.

**Demo**: [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/3/).

```
$("input[name=task-group]").keydown(function (e){
if(e.keyCode == 13){
    $("input[name=task-group]").blur();
}
});
```

Comment: u made my day! TQ!
do u have rough idea how to append a new 'add' link when the user enter and set something on the available one?

i think just continue to append it after the key press and blur function right.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/4/).
Added solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=task-group]").hide();

    var addBtn = $("#add");
    var inputBar = $("input[name=task-group]");

    $("#add").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(inputBar).show().focus();
    });

$("input[name=task-group]").blur(function(){
        if($(inputBar).val() != ""){
        $(this).hide();
        var new_task_group  = $(this).val();
        $(addBtn).text(new_task_group);
        $(addBtn).show();
        } // if close 
        else {
            $(addBtn).show();
            $(inputBar).hide();
        }
    }); 
    });
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed
      $("input[name=task-group]").blur();
  }
});
```